# mysql access from netbeans 8.1 is very slow

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I have the following installed on my laptop:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- MySQL 5.5
- Netbeans 8.1

Connecting to MYSQL databases from "Services" menu of Netbeans takes unusually long, upto 1 min or more. The commands like connect, disconnect work in very erratic fashion, sometimes not responding  at all.  If I try to retrieve tables or schema it occasionally hangs.

I have used MySQL workbench to create the databases. However, creating / updating the database structures from Netbeans itself takes too much time.
Earlier I had Netbeans 8.0, had the same problem so have installed Netbeans 8.1.

Netbeans comes by default with Derby database and have had no problems with Derby  Database.

Are there any parameters that need to be set for MYSQL to work correctly with Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check what is the connector that NetBeans is using to connect to MySQL? It might be the slow connector for MySQL which might be causing the slowness.

You can get the latest MySQL connector from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Moreover when you are connecting to MySQL from Workbench you are connecting via SSH Tunnel which is way too faster.

Apache Derby is in-memory database so comparing it to connect to MySQL from Netbeans IDE is a not very relevant. But if you are connecting to Derby and MySQL from NetBeans via JDBC driver then it's comparable...most probably you need to focus on the MySQL connector that is being used in NetBeans IDE to connect to MySQL.

*When i am connecting to MySQL from the Java IDEs...i generally do all the DDL operations from the MySQL shell and only DML operations i perform from the Java IDE(via Java programs).*

Comment: Please help me with:

Comment: How do I check which connector is being used by Netbeans? How do I install the MySQL Connector (have downloaded it and extracted the file in a temporary folder) and configure Netbeans to use the latest connector?

Comment: You can check these two links(https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) and (https://netbeans.org/competition/win-with-netbeans/mysql-client.html)

Comment: It works. Thanks Ashu.  I created a new driver in Netbeans with latest version of MySql JDBC connector. Now under "Drivers" it shows both the old driver and new driver. When I create a connection for MySql server it automatically uses the new driver (don't know how it decides which driver to use). There is no performance issue.  I am wondering if there is a way to modify the properties of the old driver so that it uses the latest jar file.

Comment: @neelanshu. DB pools in App container accepts the latest successful DB connection. In case of NetBeans that might be the case. Glad your problem is resolved. Please accept the answer(by clicking the tick mark).